# find all rows after the recent update using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried below query to bring all rows after last Action="UNLOCKED", but ORDER BY is not allowed in subquery it seems.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE id >= (SELECT MAX(id) 
FROM TABLE  
WHERE ACTION='UNLOCKED' AND action_id=123 
ORDER BY CREATE_DATE DESC);
```

Sample data

```
Id action_id Action ... CREATE_DATE
1  123       ADD        03/18/2018
2  123       Unlocked   03/19/2018
3  123       Updated1   03/19/2018
4  123       Updated2   03/19/2018
5  123       Unlocked   03/20/2018
6  123       Updated3   03/20/2018
7  123       Updated4   03/20/2018
```

Output should be rows with id 5,6,7. What should i use to get this output

Comment: You don't need an `ORDER BY` in the subquery; the `MAX()` aggregate function works well enough without it. I think maybe you want it *outside* the subquery?

Comment: What about other action_ids? Do you only want to show 123 or others too? (As is your query selects all records with high IDs regardless of the action_id.)

Comment: I used ACTION='UNLOCKED' and action_id=123 filter condition again in the actual query and removed order by and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use an inner join on subselect for max create_date

```
select * from TABLE 
INNER JOIN  (
select max(CREATE_DATE) max_date
from TABLE
where Action = 'Unlocked' ) T on t.max_date = TABLE.CREATE_DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not order the inner query because it will return only one value. You can do it as follows

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id >= (select max(id) from TABLE  where ACTION='UNLOCKED' and action_id=123);
```